Using Descartes rule of signs with $0$ coefficients
How do I work with Descartes rule of signs with $0$ coefficients for some polynomial? For example $3x^4-3x^2+3x-2$?

Yes.  In your example there are $3$ sign changes.  Zero coefficients are ignored.  Descartes then tells you that this polynomial has either $3$ or $1$ positive zeros.

thanks very much

could you put that as an answer so I can put that it is correct? (if it is correct)

changes approved

Yes.
In your example there are $3$ sign changes. Zero coefficients are ignored. Descartes then tells you that this polynomial has either $3$ or $1$ positive zeros.
